# Send/receive Multiple Requests From Server and Cient While Server Maintains Defined Variables and Temporary Files

Tags: javascript, php, websocket

I wrote an API that processes different file types and lets the user download them via client side when finished. The issue I am running into is that sometimes while processing the file, the next step while processing is sometimes not clear and requires the user to make a decision. Without having to move the entire process client side my goal is to:

Id like to upload the file, during the processing, if a fork-in-the-road situation comes up. The server responds with a question, the user selects the option, then the server continues to process and then sends the file to the user.
I am using `PHP $_POST/$_FILES` variables sent from the `JS Fetch` requests. The issue I have is that any new requests to the server are NEW and all variables are undefined and I cant access that previous 'Session' of processing. The server is not waiting to hear back either.
 How can I send a response back to the client, and wait for their response? I want the server to keep variables and temporary files defined so that when the response from the client comes back, it can continue processing. How to achieve this? I am open to using NodeJS if I need to.

Here is an example of what I am trying to do:

```
fetch('/api',{
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {'Accept': 'application/json'},
    body:JSON.stringify{initRequest:'fileData'})
})
.then(r => r.json())
.then(function(r){
    if(r['200']==='Make Decision'){
        //show HTML that gives decisions, then sends decision back to PHP
    }
})
```

PHP

```
$fileData = $_POST['initRequest'];
//FILE PROCESSING, send decision request
echo json_encode(['200'=>'Make Decision']);
```

After sending decision to API

```
$decision = $_POST['Decision'];
if($decision === 'xxx'){
   //CONTINUE PROCESSING WITH $fileData that was previously defined in previous request
}
echo json_encode(['200'=>'Download new file link']);
```

Web sockets? Long polling? DataStream? Pipelining? I have been researching for a few hours and cant find an example or a concrete method of doing this. Thanks!

Comment: You said it yourself...Session. put the variables in the Session between requests. That's what it's there for.

Comment: @ADyson Thanks, but per my question, I would consider that a workaround. Unless of course that is the only way to achieve what my question is asking for.

Comment: Web applications are stateless. Once a HTTP request has completed, anything that happened in that request is forgotten by the server, by default. If you make some information available so that the server can access that info in a second request, then you need to store it somewhere. If it's only needed temporarily, then the Session is a good storage option. It's not a workaround, it's fundamental to web application design.